# When to use "do" in phrases which are not questions?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Example: You do need to drink more water.

or

You need to drink more water.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *do* there adds emphasis and affirmation. Like if I told you

> Me: You need to drink more water
>
> You: I drink enough water
>
> *you go to the ER for dehydration*
>
> Me: You do need to drink more water!

I'm emphasizing that I was correct and you weren't getting enough water. Or if someone says

> 1: You didn't read that book.
>
> 2: I *did* read the book

you're emphasizing that you in fact did read that book; it's stronger than

> I read the book

Addition: It's also used to ask questions, in verb tenses that don't use an auxiliary verb:

> Do you exercise every morning?
> Did you drive to the party?

But:

> Have you exercised this morning?
> Are you driving to the party?
> Were you exercising this morning at about 6 o'clock?